# Facebook/Python is fan page liked? -n00b-

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

Hi I use this code in php for check if fan page is liked using signed_request:

```
    private function parsePageSignedRequest()  
    { 
        if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))  
        { 
            $encoded_sig = null; 
            $payload = null; 
            list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2); 
            $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/')); 
            $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true)); 
            return $data; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 

    function isLiked() 
    { 
        $signed_request = $this->parsePageSignedRequest(); 

        if($signed_request->page->liked)  
        { 
            return true; 
        } else { 
            return false;                 
        } 
    }
```

how I can write this for python/django?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use one of the following SDK's

[python](https://github.com/jmg/pyfb)

[django](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango)

Comment: thanks you give me a clue, this is the answer I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853073/creating-a-like-gate-reveal-tab-for-a-facebook-app-using-django-python
testing...

Comment: No problem ;) i hope you get it done